# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks(i.e.<% ...%>) ajax toolkit html editor

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, master-pages, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master/111.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Template.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Template" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphhead" Runat="Server">   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../css-js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphcontent" Runat="Server">
     <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" Width="1028px" Height="300px" runat="server" SuppressTabInDesignMode="true" ActiveMode="Design" />                  
</asp:Content>


 <asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphFooterJS" Runat="Server">
        </asp:Content>
```

I try to add master page ajax html editor with namespace but I have this err:
*System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).*

how to fix it? thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 30):

I have faced this error before. Solution is, check in your master page, if you have javascript with <% ... %> block, then remove it from head and add in body section.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think, error reason is not js. When I removed ajaxtoolkit part,there is no err

Comment: You solved my problem, i just had to put the whole scripts in the conetnetholder head.

Answer (score 9):

Use This

1-Replace the code block with <%# instead of <%=

After replace code block with <%# instead of <%= add following code in page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Page.Header.DataBind();    
}
```

After add code run your application it will work for you.

Happy Coding………

Answer (score 2):

Thank you - this was also my issue.

I altered:

```
 <script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl(String.Format("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1{0}.js", IIf(Bshifter4.MvcApplication.UseMinify, ".min", ".chirp")))%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove javascript block from header and add to body.

Answer (score 0):

Any databinding expressions in a tag with runat=server with throw this error.

Answer (score -2):

You should wrap  around your script tags

Comment: Downvoted because there is no detail as to what the OP should do